# ApkTool won't let me do anything

Tags: java, android, apk, apktool

I have a folder I need to be compiled into an APK for my phone, I've followed all the installation instructions on https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/install/

When I type java `java -jar apktool.jar apktool b /Users/jordan/Desktop/PieMessage-master`

I get this:

```
I: Using Apktool 2.2.0
Exception in thread "main" brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.directory.DirectoryException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: b (No such file or directory)
at brut.androlib.Androlib.readMetaFile(Androlib.java:258)
at brut.androlib.Androlib.build(Androlib.java:270)
at brut.androlib.Androlib.build(Androlib.java:263)
at brut.apktool.Main.cmdBuild(Main.java:224)
at brut.apktool.Main.main(Main.java:84)
Caused by: brut.directory.DirectoryException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: b (No such file or directory)
at brut.directory.ZipRODirectory.<init>(ZipRODirectory.java:55)
at brut.directory.ZipRODirectory.<init>(ZipRODirectory.java:38)
at brut.androlib.res.util.ExtFile.getDirectory(ExtFile.java:55)
at brut.androlib.Androlib.readMetaFile(Androlib.java:254)
... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: b (No such file or directory)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:163)
at brut.directory.ZipRODirectory.<init>(ZipRODirectory.java:53)
... 7 more
```

Comment: What is the `b` for in the command? The apktool does not like it there.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but it has many views. I'll share my solution as I had this problem. This should work:

`java -jar apktool.jar b /Users/jordan/Desktop/PieMessage-master`

Answer (score -1):

Try this and see if it works:

`java -jar apktool.jar apktool /Users/jordan/Desktop/PieMessage-master`